# What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

My text tells me this:

[image]

And, Wolfram tells me this:

[image]

Now, I'm not certain what to believe, but I believe I'm not certain because I'm not certain if Wolfram is using the logarithm with base $10$. However, I believe that if Wolfram is correct then my text is wrong since its clear that at $x=1$ the series given by Wolfram diverges.

Which radius of convergence is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, your textbook just add the fact that the series converges for $x=1$.

Comment: But Wolfram says it doesn't?

Comment: At $x=1$, the series is the alternating harmonic series, which converges.  WA says that it converges for $|x|<1$, which it does.  It also converges for $x=1$.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú Wolfram Alpha probably doesn't check the end points of the interval of convergence so that's why it doesn't show that it also converges for $x=1$. You should always remember to check them while solving such exercises.

Comment: Oops, I guess the others were too fast to be right.

Comment: Wolfram only gives you a sufficient condition but not a necessary condition.

Comment: @Dr.MV that's what I kind of meant :)

Comment: Actually, the Wolfram answer also tells us that it converges for complex numbers $x$ with $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WA has an incomplete answer.  Inasmuch as the McLaurin series for $\log (1+x)$ is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

we see that the series converges for $|x|<1$ from, say for example, the ratio test.  Checking the end points, we see that for $x=1$ the series is the convergent alternating harmonic series while for $x=-1$ the series is the divergent harmonic series.  Thus, the interval of convergence is

$$-1<x\le 1$$

Comment: Do you know a link that proves the alternating harmonic series converges.

Comment: Yes.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) you will see a well-known general result.  If the terms of an alternating series are decreasing to $0$, the series converges.

Comment: doesn't the ratio test only check for absolute convergence? What if this series is conditionally convergent for some $a > 1$?

Comment: The ratio test applies here when $|x|<1$.   See the link in the comment that precedes yours.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x=1$ then you get $$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$$

which is convergent. This can be seen by rewriting it using $$\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

$$\left(\frac1{2}\right)+\frac16+\frac1{30}+\frac1{56}+\cdots<\frac1{2}+\frac14+\frac1{25}+\frac1{49}+\cdots<\frac1{2}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}$$

On the other hand, it is easy to see it is positive, furthermore, the differences $\frac{1}{k}$ are getting increasingly close to zero, so it will converge to a finite value.

Answer (score 1):

Both sources are correct, but your textbook is more comprehensive than Wolfram.

Any power series has a radius of convergence, where the series converges for any number inside the radius and diverges for any number outside the radius. Wolfram correctly says that the radius of convergence is $1$.

However, for real numbers, the two points *at* the radius of convergence may either converge or diverge. Wolfram does not address those points at all. Note that it says that the series converges for $|x|<1$: it does not say what happens when $|x|=1$. Your textbook does, and says it correctly.

The series does converge for $x=1$ since it is then an alternating series where the terms decrease in absolute value and tend to zero. I'm sure you know the theorem that says such a series converges. The series diverges at $x=-1$ since it is then the negative of the harmonic series, which famously diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram is using the natural logarithm, $\log x = \ln x$ in general, unless a base is specified.

And whilst Wolfram is correct, your textbook provides a more comprehensive reasoning, since at $x=1$, the series is the alternating harmonic series, which converges.

Comment: At $x=1$, the series is the alternating harmonic series, which converges.