# Find $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^k \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, geometric-series

I want to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^k \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$

I'm not sure what to do here. Without the $a^k$ term, it's a simple telescoping series, but that term changes everything. I tried writing out the first few terms but could not come up with anything that doesn't turn right back into the original series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Using [What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x),

for $-1\le x<1,$

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{x^k}k$$

Now $$a^k\left(\dfrac1k-\dfrac1{k+1}\right)=\dfrac{a^k}k-\dfrac1a\cdot\dfrac{a^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

Comment: (+1) BTW, I think there is no need of that link. Why do you think so?

Comment: @JaideepKhare, For proof

Comment: There is no proof in that thread, it's just a question asking whether we can use the series for $x=-1$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{a}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

Now see that 
$$\frac{d^2}{da^2}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k-1} =\frac{1}{a(1-a)} = \frac{1}{a-1} -\frac{1}{a}$$

> **Edit: added** about the constants of integration see that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 0~~~\text{for} ~~a=0$$ 
>   and 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k+1}  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k+1} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)= 1 ~~~\text{for} ~~a=1$$

Comment: Amazing (+1) ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I get that result, but then what? Integrate twice and figure out what to do with the constants of integration?

Comment: For the constants of integration take $a= 0$ and $a=1$ in the initial sum you will fine them. See the edit if it answers your question.

Comment: But integrating $\int (\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{1}{a})\, da = \log(a-1)+\log(a) + C_1$, and that is undefined when $a$ is 0 or 1. And why did we not take the derivative of the $1/a$ term in the first place? I am so lost :(

Comment: That integral is not correct there is Minus instead of plus. also dont forget you have to integrate twice