# Proving this complicated limit!

Tags: limits

I have to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_\limits{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \ln2$.

The hints I have are:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_\limits{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} - \ln(n) = c < \infty$

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac {1}{i} - 2\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2i} $

I never calculated any limits with sum in the formula, nor I see how the tips are of any help.

Would appreciate a few hints and tips!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x

Comment: The second hint should be $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac {1}{i} - 2\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} - \ln(n+1)$. Then the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing: 
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\geq 0$$
and bounded above (show that part).
Then the sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges to a finite limit $c$.
Hence, by the second hint,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} &= \sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac {1}{i} - 2\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2i}\\
&=\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac {1}{i}-\ln(2n+1)\right) - \left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}-\ln(n+1)\right)+\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\right)\\
&\to c-c+\ln(2)=\ln(2).
\end{align}$$
Finally note that
$$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}
=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}+
\frac{1}{2n+1}\to \ln(2)+0=\ln(2).$$