# ln(2) series bijective equivalence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to get a **bijective proof** of the equivalence of the following infinite series which are easy to evaluate as $\ln(2)$ using elementary calculus tools:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n2^n}}$$

I tried **grouping terms** in (1) as has lower absolute value decreasing speed and is alternating to get terms in (2) as it has faster decrease and is positive defined. But no success on it.

Comment: What's a bijective proof?

Comment: A bijective proof consists on grouping terms in both series to form group sums in a way to get a bijection between them. For instance $$\sum{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}$$ is equivalent to $$\sum{\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}}$$ as second is obtained grouping terms in the first series 2 by 2 sequentially.

Comment: Just to add that no "increasing gaps" (sum more and more distant terms in each group) are allowed in those groupings in order to ensure that no term is left alone with no group when passing into the infinite sum approach.

Comment: One cannot expect that such a “grouping equivalence” always exists. As an example, the series $1+0+0+\ldots$ and $1/2+1/4+1/8 + \ldots$ converge to the same value, but no (finite) groups have the same sum.

Comment: Agree on that, but also can not suppose it does not exist because sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Of course proof of non existence of such a bijection will be also recognized as an anwser to this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum the series of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655243/sum-the-series-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac12n-n)

Comment: @DietrichBurde How does the linked question answer this one?